# how to merge every element of a list to other element in R

Tags: r, list, merge, compare

Suppose: I want to compare all the elements and get the final value in Excel sheet. I'm converting my list elements into data.frames and then merging them. Its working fine when I do it manually but when I try to do in a loop I'm unable to it. I want to merge all the elements of the list and store them in a variable (mer3) which can be exported into an Excel sheet

```
list1 = list("abc","def","ghi","jkl")

[...
extra code to convert every list element into data.frame
df_abc
df_def
df_ghi
df_jkl
]

mer1 <- merge(df_abc,df_def, all = TRUE)
mer2 <- merge(mer1,df_ghi, all = TRUE)
mer3 <- merge(mer2,df_jkl, all = TRUE)

write.xlsx(mer3, file="mydata.xlsx",sheetName="merged data list")
```

Sample data: (as per suggestions below, but it shows null after execution of merge commands in loop)

```
> DF_list1
[[1]]
  webId  name
1 UA-4  Auth
2 UA-4  Cat
3 UA-4  Sub Cat
[[2]]
  webId  name
1 UA-6  Auth
2 UA-6  Visit
3 UA-6  Sub Cat
[[3]]
  webId  name
1 UA-7  Session
2 UA-7  Cat
3 UA-7  Sub Cat

merged <- DF_list1[[1]] 
for (m in 2:length(DF_list1))
merged <- merge(merged, DF_list1[[m]])
```

Comment: What is your expected output for `list1` ?

Comment: `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))`???

Comment: @akrun: I want all the list element which are converted into required df's to be merged in a single file (mer3)

Comment: your data starts off as a list, so keep it as a list rather than producing individually named objects. Then you can just loop through the list.

Comment: @dash2: cool it sounds right! but let's say that I have created a list of my required df's, say df_list, and then I want to merge df_list[1] with df_list[2] and then store in mer1 then again merge mer1 with df_list[3], will it be done so..

Comment: `merged <- df_list[[1]]; for (l in 2:length(df_list)) merged <- merge(merged, df_list[[l]])`. Works so long as `df_list` has 2 or more members.

Comment: @dash2: I tried ur above code but not sure why I'm getting always the below result - 

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Although for the df_list[[l]] I can see the last element of the df_list but for merged it shows <0 rows>

Comment: I wish I could help but you haven't provided any sample data :-(

Comment: @dash2: added one sample data in the original question.. The sample data has 3 elements in the list, in real it may have many list elements which needs to be merged finally..

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this in a for loop like this:

```
merged <- merge(list1[[1]],list1[[2]])
for(i in 3:length(allframes)) {
  merged <- merge(merged,list1[[i]])
}
```

but if columns of dataframes is the same you can just bind them:

from R Documentation:

> do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a
>   function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

so you can pass a list of dataframes to the function rbind for merging them: (if list1 is a list of dataframes)

```
result <- do.call(rbind,list1)
```

Comment: `rbind` is not the same as `merge`.

Comment: @dash2 you're right. I misunderstood the question. added a solution for `merge` function too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Adel_Sa:  I tried ur above code but not sure why I'm getting always the below result - <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) Although for the df_list[[l]] I can see the last element of the df_list but for merged it shows <0 rows>